# Optimize select query with OR and ILIKE

Tags: postgresql, select, string-searching, gin-index

I have the following query for my PostgreSQL 13 database:

```
SELECT * FROM "user" 
INNER JOIN "comment" on "comment"."user_id" = "user"."id"
WHERE "user"."biography" ILIKE '%SomeString%' 
   OR "comment"."text" ILIKE '%SomeString%';
```

I have a GIN index defined on `user` `biography` and another one on `comment` `text`

```
CREATE INDEX user_bio_idx ON "user" USING gin ("biography" gin_trgm_ops);
CREATE INDEX comment_txt_idx ON "comment" USING gin ("text" gin_trgm_ops);
```

Unfortunately, running `EXPLAIN ANALYZE ...` on my select query reveals that the indexes are not being used and the query is taking 4 to 5 seconds.

How can I improve its performance?  (I already tried `UNION` and even concatenating the two columns)

Comment: "I already tried UNION"  so what happened?

Comment: UNION with pg_trgm indexes works fine for me.